# How to use clang post compilation from source?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I have downloaded [LLVM 3.6](http://llvm.org/releases/3.6.0/llvm-3.6.0.src.tar.xz) + [CFE](http://llvm.org/releases/3.6.0/cfe-3.6.0.src.tar.xz) + [Compiler-RT](http://llvm.org/releases/3.6.0/compiler-rt-3.6.0.src.tar.xz). Post compilation, below are the list of executables generated:

### llvm-3.6.0/build/bin

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 51113672 Aug  4 15:25 arcmt-test
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 36545319 Aug  4 14:25 bugpoint
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan    13710 Aug  4 15:25 c-arcmt-test
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan   124687 Aug  4 15:25 c-index-test
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dipanjan dipanjan        0 Aug  4 15:02 clang-3.6
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 51741074 Aug  4 15:25 clang-check
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  3945674 Aug  4 15:23 clang-format
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  2776541 Aug  4 14:27 clang-tblgen
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan     8809 Aug  4 14:18 count
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  5951029 Aug  4 15:02 diagtool
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan   892952 Aug  4 14:18 FileCheck
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 66957023 Aug  4 14:22 llc
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 42129985 Aug  4 14:23 lli
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan   384911 Aug  4 14:23 lli-child-target
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 16546687 Aug  4 14:22 llvm-ar
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  5769950 Aug  4 14:22 llvm-as
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan   780247 Aug  4 14:25 llvm-bcanalyzer
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan   467751 Aug  4 14:21 llvm-config
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  2608867 Aug  4 14:23 llvm-cov
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 48917700 Aug  4 14:26 llvm-c-test
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  5504873 Aug  4 14:23 llvm-diff
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  4831508 Aug  4 14:22 llvm-dis
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  1701984 Aug  4 14:24 llvm-dsymutil
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  2442042 Aug  4 14:24 llvm-dwarfdump
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  6439822 Aug  4 14:23 llvm-extract
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  6678768 Aug  4 14:23 llvm-link
-rwxr-x--- 1 dipanjan dipanjan     1704 Aug  4 13:36 llvm-lit
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 56954541 Aug  4 14:27 llvm-lto
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 14644360 Aug  4 14:22 llvm-mc
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan   665654 Aug  4 14:25 llvm-mcmarkup
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 16587218 Aug  4 14:23 llvm-nm
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 20046537 Aug  4 14:24 llvm-objdump
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan    36311 Aug  4 14:18 llvm-PerfectShuffle
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  2968803 Aug  4 14:23 llvm-profdata
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dipanjan dipanjan        7 Aug  4 14:22 llvm-ranlib -> llvm-ar
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  7230376 Aug  4 14:24 llvm-readobj
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 13489409 Aug  4 14:24 llvm-rtdyld
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  6594901 Aug  4 14:23 llvm-size
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  7009337 Aug  4 14:25 llvm-stress
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  7535042 Aug  4 14:25 llvm-symbolizer
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  7133647 Aug  4 13:38 llvm-tblgen
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  6788419 Aug  4 14:24 llvm-vtabledump
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  6458851 Aug  4 14:24 macho-dump
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan   399734 Aug  4 14:18 not
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  7013768 Aug  4 14:26 obj2yaml
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan 75706398 Aug  4 14:22 opt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  6443534 Aug  4 14:25 verify-uselistorder
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan  1633631 Aug  4 14:26 yaml2obj
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dipanjan dipanjan   830293 Aug  4 14:18 yaml-bench
```

My question is: The file `llvm-3.6.0/build/bin/clang-3.6` is a zero-byte file. How can I use `clang` in case of `llvm-3.x` even?

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong in your build. It should not be 0 bytes. It seems like you've made a debug build, so the `clang` binary should be enormous (hundreds of MB). Perhaps your build ran out of memory?

You can also consider downloading the binary drops of Clang+LLVM.

Comment: Even I tried on my friend's system running Ubuntu 14.04 x64. Same happened.